Move pixel from personal Facebook ad account to business ad account
I originally started advertising my business under a personal ad account on Facebook. I've now set up a Business ad account, and I want to be able to use the same pixel under it. However, it doesn't seem like there's an obvious way to do this. I tried to follow the instructions here, but these steps seem deprecated: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/622772416185967
Can someone please explain how I might do this?
